# How to handle 200Million row compare of DB Table with 100.000 Subset on a XML file?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I am currently writing an application that needs to be able to select a subset of IDs from Millions of users...

I am currently writing software to select a group of 100.000 IDs from a table that contains the whole list of Brazilian population 200.000.000 (200M), I need to be able to do this in a reasonable amount of time... ID on Table = ID on XML

I am thinking of parsing the xml file and starting a thread that performs a SELECT statement on a database, I would need a connection for each thread, still this way seems like a brute force approach, perhaps there is a more elegant way?

1) what is the best database to do this?
2) what is a reasonable limit to the amount of db connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making 100.000 queries would take a long time, and splitting up the work on separate threads won't help you much as you are reading from the same table.

Don't get a single record at a time, rather divide the 100.000 items up in reasonably small batches, for example 1000 items each, which you can send to the database. Create a temporary table in the database with those id values, and make a join against the database table to get those records.

Using MS SQL Server for example, you can send a batch of items as an XML to a stored procedure, which can create the temporary table from that and query the database table.

Comment: That is very interesting, I have never worked with batch of items, do you have any pointers for me to follow? Code or Articles that explain this approach in greater detail?

Comment: @AdamSurfari: Here is an article about sending data in XML to a stored procedure: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/02/16/passing-lists-to-sql-server-2005-with-xml-parameters.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Any modern DBMS that can handle an existing 200M row table, should have no problem comparing against a 100K row table (assuming your hardware is up to scratch).

Ideal solution: Import your XML (at least the IDs) into to a new table, ensure the columns you're comparing are indexed correctly. And then query.

Comment: That is an interesting approach, how long will it take to import a file like that? I need to provide results via a web service, so ideally I can change the XML file easily.

Comment: How long is a piece of string? I don't know how big your XML file is , what kind of hardware you're running on, how heavily it's loaded, what DMBS you're using, or what you're parsing the XML with.

Comment: That said, I would expect any modern PC to be able to parse through large (100-200MB) XML files in the order of a few seconds using .NET (assuming you're just pulling out IDs). Measure it, it's a pretty simple task.

Answer (score 0):

What language? If your using .NET you could load your XML and SQL as datasources, and then i believe there are some enumerable functions that could be used to compare the data.

Comment: I will be using C# to provide a webservice that returns these values.

Comment: That would require you to load all the 200M rows! This does not only fill your memory but creates a huge network traffic!

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

- Parse the XML and store the extracted IDs into a temporary table<sup>1</sup>.
- From the main table, select only the rows whose ID is also present in the temporary table:

  SELECT * FROM MAIN_TABLE WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TEMPORARY_TABLE)

A decent DBMS will typically do the job quicker than you can, even if you employed batching/chunking and parallelization on your end.

---

*<sup>1</sup> Temporary tables are typically created using `CREATE [GLOBAL|LOCAL] TEMPORARY TABLE ...` syntax and you'll probably want it private for the session (check your DBMS's interpretation of `GLOBAL` vs. `LOCAL` for this). If your DBMS of choice doesn't support temporary tables, you can use "normal" tables instead, but be careful not to let concurrent sessions mess with that table while you are still using it.*